# Ubuntu Snappy Core Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I tried installing Ubuntu Snappy Core on Raspberry Pi 3 and did not have any luck with boot up process. The rainbow screen is the only image that will display. Does Snappy work on Raspberry Pi 3 as stated on download page?

Comment: The unofficial image for Raspberry Pi 3 at [ARM/Raspberry Pi - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) webpage is not supported directly by Canonical. Still waiting for Canonical to release an official Raspberry Pi 3 image.

Answer (score 2):

There are images available for the Raspberry Pi 3 for Ubuntu Core 16, they are in beta quality and will be released soon:

- Announcement: https://lists.snapcraft.io/archives/snapcraft/2016-September/001166.html
- Images: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-snappy/16.04/current/

Comment: newest images you can get here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/xenial/daily-preinstalled/current/